# Fix or undo detached head on tag

Tags: git, github

Hey all i could really use some help here with my situation,

I created an empty repo and added a tag to it, and pointed that repo in Zenodo for doi creation
later i pushed certain files to the repo i am really not sure how i goofed this up
but i think i may have merged tag to main
and i no longer have the tag live
when i clone it the first message i get is

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v1.0 repourl
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Note: checking out 'xxx'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

is there a way i can fix this its really critical for me to have files in the tag
i can see the tag online and so does zenodo
only thing is that there are no files in there, however they can be found in the main branch.
Since i am in not position to change the zenodo link, is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. To improve this question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) then edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There's nothing here to fix, at least in what you've asked.

#### Long (ish)

The output you have posted contains no mistakes or errors.  Your *question*, however, is full of assumptions and statements that just aren't true.  Git is notoriously hard for (or unfriendly to) beginners and you have hit several of its classic items.

First: files aren't stored in tags.  In fact, Git doesn't *store files* in the first place.  What Git stores are *commits*.  A Git repository is, to a large extent, just a big collection of commits.  So this should immediately leave you with the question: *What, exactly, is a commit?*

Some of the details don't matter yet, so we'll skip over them.  The most important two are these:

- Each commit is numbered.  The numbers, however, aren't simple counting numbers: they don't go "commit #1", then "commit #2", followed by #3 and so on.  Instead, each number is unique but *huge and random-looking*.  It's expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and looks like [<sup><sub>`d486ca60a51c9cb1fe068803c3f540724e95e83a`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d486ca60a51c9cb1fe068803c3f540724e95e83a).  This number is how Git actually *finds* the commit, in the repository.  But humans generally don't deal with the numbers directly: they're too big and ugly and impossible to type in correctly.
- Each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  This is how Git keeps files, even though it doesn't store them *as* files.  Git stores *commits*, and the commits then store the files, as a sort of archive, like a tarball or zip archive or RAR or whatever.

In order to *find* the commits in a repository, Git gives us several kinds of names.  The two most important are *branch names* and *tag names*.  **Both kinds of names just store one raw commit hash ID.**  This means that when you use the name, you get that particular commit.  The key difference between a branch name and a tag name, here, is that *branch names select a different commit at different times*.  More precisely, a *branch name* names the *latest* commit that is "on" that branch.  Make a later commit, and the branch name will—*must*—change.  A *tag name*, however, names *one specific commit forever*.

With that in mind:

> I created an empty repo

So far, all is OK.  An empty repository is one with no commits in it.  Since it has no commits, it *cannot* have any branch or tag names: a branch or tag name *must* contain the hash ID of some commit that exists in that repository.<sup>1</sup>

Note that when GitHub creates a new repository for you, they will (optionally) put one initial commit *into* the new repository, so that branch and tag names can come into existence.  This creates the initial branch name—which used to be `master` but is now `main`, on GitHub.

> and added a tag to it

This part is not possible.  There has to have been at least one commit.

> later i pushed certain files to the repo

What you did is create one or more *commits*.  This allowed branch and tag names to come into existence.  Then you made a tag name for one of the commits.  Each of the commits you added held some set of files, too, as a permanent archive of those particular versions of those particular files.

You now had, and presumably still have, a repository with some branch names—such as `master` and/or `main`—and at least one tag name, specifically `v1.0`.  You also used `git push` to send the new commits, and any branch name updates and new branch and tag names, to the copy of the repository over at GitHub.  These are *separate copies* of the repository, so they can get out of sync, and—this part is quite important—each copy has *its own branch names*.  The two copies *share* tag names, and *share commits*, but they each have their own *branch names*.

> ... i think i may have merged tag to main

Git's `git merge` is another rather complicated subject, but you need not worry about *tags* here.  The merge operation merges *commits*.  Tags, once made, stay put.<sup>2</sup>

> when i clone [the repository, Git says]
>
> ```
> ... You are in 'detached HEAD' state ...
> ```

This is because you are telling `git clone` that the name you want to use is `v1.0`:

> ```
> git clone ... --branch v1.0 ...
> ```

The way `git clone` works is:

1. It creates a new, empty directory.<sup>3</sup>  The remaining operations are then done *in* the new directory.
2. It creates a new, empty repository (by running `git init`, in effect).
3. It adds a *remote* to this repository (`git remote add origin url`, more or less).  This is a short name by which your Git can contact the other Git, from which you're about to copy all the commits.
4. It runs any additional `git config` operations you ask it to (you didn't, so step 4 here doesn't do anything).
5. It runs `git fetch origin`, more or less.  This normally copies *all the commits* from the other Git, but *none of the branches*.  You do, however, get all of their *tags*.  However, when using `--depth 1`, you don't get *all* the commits, nor all the tags, nor all the branches.<sup>4</sup>
6. Finally, having gotten all (or a few, or one) commit(s) from the other Git, your Git uses the argument you gave to `--branch` to choose which branch to create in your own Git repository.  If you *didn't* use `--branch`, your Git asks their Git which branch name *they* recommend.  There's a weird special case here for tags, though.

Since you did use both `--depth` (1) and `--branch` (with a tag name), you get two special-case behaviors:

- Your Git makes what Git calls a *single-branch* clone, i.e., doesn't bother to get the last commits, and earlier commits, from any of the branch names you *didn't specifically request*.
- And, since your argument to `--branch` was a *tag* name instead of a *branch* name, you actually get *no branches at all* from them.  You just copy the one commit specified by the one tag name.  Your Git then creates *no* branch names at all, and checks out that one commit, as what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.

Since you used the `--depth` flag without the `--no-single-branch` flag, you got a single-branch clone; since the branch you chose wasn't really a branch, you got a *no*-branch clone.  This kind of clone is very confusing to use.  Its main use is to do a single build, e.g., as for a release build.  It's not very good for doing real work in.

In general, those new to Git should avoid single-branch clones, avoid the `--depth` argument, and pass only *branch names* to `--branch` when using `git clone`.  (It might be better, in some sense, to use `git clone` without the `--branch` option at all, and instead provide the `-n` option to `git clone`, which makes it skip step 6 entirely.  However, then you have to do your own `git checkout` or `git switch` initially, which is not the most convenient way to get started, even though it's just one extra step.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, a tag name can contain the hash ID of something other than a commit—but in general, tags name one specific commit, even if it's indirect.  I include this footnote just to be technically correct ([the best kind of correct](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/48a9bw/why_is_technically_correct_the_best_kind_of/)).

<sup>2</sup>Technically, you can move a tag if you force it, and very old versions of Git (predating 1.8.2) accidentally applied branch-name rules to tag-names in some cases.  This was fixed long ago, but some systems still come with Git 1.7 (!).  If you're using such an ancient system, you should probably upgrade, if at all possible.  GitHub are using a much more modern Git (in fact GitHub drive some of the updates *to* Git, at times) so they, at least, don't have this tag issue.

<sup>3</sup>You can tell `git clone` to take over an existing empty directory instead, but that's less common—there's not much reason to do that—and is not what you're doing here.

<sup>4</sup>The details here are absurdly complicated, though for good reasons.  Leave out the `--depth 1` and you *will* get all the commits—well, all the commits the other Git is willing to hand over, modulo certain pull request related items when using GitHub—and all the tags, even with the `--branch` argument.  Add `--no-single-branch` to `--depth 1` and you'll get all their *branch tip* commits, and maybe more tags.  That's how it all gets complicated.